# Can we clone objects like MS Word , ctrl + mouse click + drag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

on my fabricjs application i click ctrl + left mouse click , on an object, and i clone it, so far so good.
The point is that i would like to do the clone like in MS WORD, which is ctrl + click + drag.

has anyone done something like that before?
thank you , it is very important for my project.

my functions are:

```
**here i make true the flag**


 fabric.Canvas.prototype.__onMouseDown = function (e) {    
              //left click is pressed
              lpressed = true;
    }

   **if the user prsees ctrl + left mouse + move , i create a new object**
      $(document).mousemove(function(e){
          console.log('mouse move');
          if(e.ctrlKey && lpressed){
              if(canvas.getActiveObject()){
                  var actObj = canvas.getActiveObject();
                  var toBack = true;
                  addCirlceTable(canvas.getActiveObject().left,canvas.getActiveObject().top,8,45,toBack);

                  canvas.renderAll();
                  //i select the original object which it comes on the foreground, over the new object
                  canvas.fire('object:selected', {target:actObj, e:e});
                  actObj.fire('selected',{e:e});
              }
          }
      });

//here i disable the flag
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
      lpressed = false;
}
```

so , the flow of the code is this:
1. select an object
2. call a function that i create a new one
3. i put the new object on the background(under the original)
4. i re-select manually the original object
5. and i need to move the original object!

**Step 5th does not work , i have to release the left click and then re-click on the original(although it is selected) , in order to move the original object.**

Comment: Looks like the right strategy. You just need to get the mousedown/mouseup event handling right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , you are right , they are ok, and the clone process works just as i wanted , ctrl + mouse drag.
i just changed the move function , instead of the general dom event `$(document).mousemove(function(e){})`

i use the fabric move event : `canvas.on('object:moving',function(e){});`